# WCF Soap Service with Meta Data Export

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, mono

I am working on a C# WCF application. I am trying to start a soap service that is self hosted within a console application.

I want to do everything programatically as its going to be in a library which will have different values, such as URL etc for various other applications it is going to be used on.

I have added the code but when I try to start the service I am getting an error:

> The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found i n the list
>   of contracts implemented by the service Engine.SoapServer.  Add a Ser
>   viceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost
>   directly to  enable support for this contract.

Below is how I am starting the soap service

```
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_STRICT_MS_COMPLIANT") != "yes")
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_STRICT_MS_COMPLIANT", "yes");
}
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(soapServerUrl))
{
    string message = "Not starting Soap Server: URL or Port number is not set in config file";
    library.logging(methodInfo, message);
    library.setAlarm(message, CommonTasks.AlarmStatus.Medium, methodInfo);
    return;
}
baseAddress = new Uri(soapServerUrl);
host = new ServiceHost(soapHandlerType, baseAddress);
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

//basicHttpBinding.Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/";

host.AddServiceEndpoint(soapManagerInterface, basicHttpBinding, soapServerUrl);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

var meta = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
{
    //ExternalMetadataLocation = new Uri(soapServerUrl + "/CritiMon?wsdl"),
    HttpGetEnabled = true,
    HttpGetUrl = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
    HttpGetBinding = basicHttpBinding,
};
//meta.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

host.Description.Behaviors.Add(meta);

var debugBehaviour = new ServiceDebugBehavior()
{
    HttpHelpPageEnabled = true,
    HttpHelpPageUrl = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true,
    HttpHelpPageBinding = basicHttpBinding,
};

host.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior));
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(debugBehaviour);
host.Opened += new EventHandler(host_Opened);
host.Faulted += new EventHandler(host_Faulted);
host.Closed += new EventHandler(host_Closed);
host.UnknownMessageReceived += new EventHandler<UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs>(host_UnknownMessageReceived);
host.Open();
```

At the moment I am seeing this issue on Windows but I also need it work on Linux under Mono

**UPDATE**
As per Vibhu, suggestion, I have tried doing what was suggested and I am now getting a different error, so hopefully getting somewhere, the error is as follows:

> MessageVersion 'Soap11 (`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`)
>   AddressingNone
>   (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none`)'  is not
>   supported in this scenario.  Only MessageVersion 'EnvelopeNone
>   (11http://s chemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none11)
>   AddressingNone (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none`)' is supported.

**UPDATE 2**
I have done again what vibhu suggeste and the soap service is successfully starting now but I am getting an error about a mismatched content type when I try and access it from the WCF Test client bundled with VS2010.

Below is the error

```
> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:8000/CritiMon If
> this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
> have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at
> the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please
> refer to the MSDN documentation at
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
> Error    URI: http://localhost:8000/CritiMon    Metadata contains a
> reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8000/CritiMon'.  
> Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by
> service http://localhost:8000/CritiMon.  The client and service
> bindings may be mismatched.    The remote server returned an error:
> (415) Cannot process the message because the content type
> 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
> 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..HTTP GET Error    URI:
> http://localhost:8000/CritiMon    There was an error downloading
> 'http://localhost:8000/CritiMon'.    The request failed with HTTP
> status 400: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your metadata behavior before adding Mex endpoint -

```
var meta = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
{
    //ExternalMetadataLocation = new Uri(soapServerUrl + "/CritiMon?wsdl"),
    HttpGetEnabled = true,
    HttpGetUrl = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
    HttpGetBinding = basicHttpBinding,
};

 host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
```

Comment: Thanks, tried what you suggested but getting a different error now. i have updated my question

Comment: comment out HttpGetBinding in both of your service behaviors and see if it works

Comment: thanks the service is starting now but getting an error when trying to access. I have updated the question

Comment: When you add service reference from test client, add this address http://localhost:8000/CritiMon /mex (presuming http://localhost:8000/CritiMon is the baseAddress of service)

Comment: what is the value of soapServerUrl

Comment: I used http://localhost:89/Service/ as soapServerUrl value and rest part is same as your implementation. I could access the service using http://localhost:89/Service/mex.

Comment: var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:89/Service");
            var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), baseAddress);
            var basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var meta = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
            {HttpGetEnabled = true,
                HttpGetUrl = new Uri("",UriKind.Relative),};
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(meta);
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), basicHttpBinding, "");
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34002/discussion-between-vibhu-and-boardy)